Use formatted text in Excel cell when creating email
I have done VBA code to create e-mails automatically. The user texts what he wants to send in one cell. However, it is not capturing font formatting, such as bold, italic, underline or font color. I want the user to be as free as possible to have multiple formatted words in his text and VBA to capture that while creating the e-mails.
Sub CriarEmails()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Nome As String
    Dim Email As String
    Dim Anexos As String
    Dim AnexoArray() As String
    Dim Assunto As String
    Dim NumeroConta As String
    Dim CorpoCompleto As String
    Dim Corpo As String
    Dim Anexo As Variant
    Dim CorpoHTML As String
    
    ' Defina o caminho do modelo de e-mail
    Dim ModeloPath As String
    ModeloPath = "C:\Users\rcoquejo\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Modelo.oft" ' Altere para o caminho correto do seu modelo
    
    ' Defina a planilha que contém os dados
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clientes")
     Set wsAT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assunto_Texto")
    
    ' Obter o texto do corpo do e-mail da célula G2
    CorpoCompleto = wsAT.Range("C3").Value
    
    ' Obter o assunto do e-mail da célula F2 (opcional)
    Assunto = wsAT.Range("B3").Value
   
    ' Inicialize o Outlook
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Loop pelos dados
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        NumeroConta = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Nome = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Email = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Anexos = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        
        
        ' Substituir o marcador pelo número da conta no assunto
        AssuntoFormatado = Replace(Assunto, "{NUMERO_CONTA}", NumeroConta)
        
        ' Crie um novo e-mail a partir de um modelo
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(ModeloPath)
        
        ' Defina o assunto
        OutMail.Subject = AssuntoFormatado
        
        ' Corpo do e-mail e Assunto
        Corpo = Replace(CorpoCompleto, "NOME", Nome)
        
        
        ' Converter quebras de linha para <br> e garantir a formatação HTML
        CorpoHTML = "<html><body>" & Replace(Replace(Corpo, vbCrLf, "<br>"), vbLf, "<br>") & "</body></html>"
        
    
        ' Criar o e-mail com o corpo HTML
        With OutMail
            .To = Email
            .BodyFormat = 2 ' HTML
            .HTMLBody = CorpoHTML
            
            ' Adicionar anexos
            AnexoArray = Split(Anexos, ";")
            For Each Anexo In AnexoArray
                If Trim(Anexo) <> "" Then
                    .Attachments.Add Trim(Anexo)
                End If
            Next Anexo
            
            ' Mostrar o e-mail
            .Display
        End With
        
        ' Limpe o objeto OutMail
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i
    
    ' Limpe o objeto OutApp
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub


Here's one way if you're on Windows:
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print CellHtml([b2])

    'how you might use this in your existing code
    Dim Anexos As String
    Anexos = CellHtml(ws.Cells(i, 4))
    'etc
End Sub

Function CellHtml(c As Range)
    Dim ie As Object, doc As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "about:blank" 'empty page
    Do While ie.Busy And Timer - t < 2 'wait till loaded
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set doc = ie.Document
    doc.Open "text/html" 'adding an editable div...
    doc.Write "<div id='editor' contenteditable='true' type='text'></div>"
    doc.Close
    doc.getElementById("editor").Focus  'pasting here
    c.Copy                              'copy the cell
    ie.ExecWB 13, 2                     'paste into the div
    CellHtml = doc.getElementById("editor").getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerHTML
    ie.Quit
End Function

Source cell:

Output HTML:
<font face="Arial">this <font size="6">is</font> a
<strong> test</strong> of<font color="#ff0000"> formatting</font> 
<u>some</u> <em>te<font size="7">x</font>t</em></font>

Output HTML as displayed in browser:


I don't understand how that applies to my VBA. Where would it enter in the code?

Edited my example to show how you'd incorporate this into your existing code.

Sub CriarEmailsComFormatacao()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsAT As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Nome As String
    Dim Email As String
    Dim Anexos As String
    Dim AnexoArray() As String
    Dim Assunto As String
    Dim NumeroConta As String
    Dim CorpoHTML As String
    Dim Anexo As Variant
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    
    ' Defina o caminho do modelo de e-mail
    Dim ModeloPath As String
    ModeloPath = "C:\Users\rcoquejo\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Modelo.oft" ' Altere para o caminho correto do seu modelo
    
    ' Defina a planilha que contém os dados
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clientes")
    Set wsAT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assunto_Texto")
    
    ' Obter o assunto do e-mail da célula B3
    Assunto = wsAT.Range("B3").Value
    
    ' Inicialize o Outlook
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Inicialize o Word para capturar a formatação da célula
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = False
    
    ' Loop pelos dados da planilha "Clientes"
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        NumeroConta = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Nome = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Email = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Anexos = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        
        ' Substituir o marcador pelo número da conta no assunto
        AssuntoFormatado = Replace(Assunto, "{NUMERO_CONTA}", NumeroConta)
        
        ' Copiar o conteúdo da célula (formatação incluída) para o Word
        wsAT.Range("C3").Copy
        
        ' Criar um novo documento no Word
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        WordDoc.Content.Paste ' Colar o conteúdo com formatação
        
        ' Obter o conteúdo do Word como HTML
        CorpoHTML = WordDoc.Content.XML ' Extrai o HTML do Word
        
        ' Substituir o marcador "NOME" no corpo do e-mail
        CorpoHTML = Replace(CorpoHTML, "NOME", Nome)
        
        ' Criar o e-mail com o corpo formatado em HTML
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(ModeloPath)
        
        With OutMail
            .To = Email
            .Subject = AssuntoFormatado
            .BodyFormat = 2 ' HTML
            .HTMLBody = CorpoHTML
            
            ' Adicionar anexos
            AnexoArray = Split(Anexos, ";")
            For Each Anexo In AnexoArray
                If Trim(Anexo) <> "" Then
                    .Attachments.Add Trim(Anexo)
                End If
            Next Anexo
            
            ' Mostrar o e-mail
            .Display
        End With
        
        ' Fechar o documento do Word sem salvar
        WordDoc.Close False
        Set WordDoc = Nothing
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i
    
    ' Limpar os objetos
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Are you posting this as an answer to your original question?  If Yes, please add some commentary to clarify that.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
